# Method asPoint().x() doesn't work in QGIS 3.4.3 but did in 3.4.1

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have built a plugin which does essentially this
[equal sized polygons along line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173127/generating-equal-sized-polygons-along-line-with-pyqgis)
Main parts of the code are from user lejedi76

I have used this plugin for months now and it worked as expected. Turning from QGIS 3.4.1 to 3.4.1 I get the following error:

> Null geometry cannot be converted to a point

I know what the error means, but I do not know why it even shows up. I also could not find the critical changes in the QGIS version that caused this problem. It seems I am overlooking something very simple, but what?
The code provided works without any problems in the QGIS 3.4.1 Python console:

```
width = 142.365
height = 79.842
overlap = 0.2
gridPath = r'C://qgistesting/testgrid.shp'

#to test take a line-layer with one feature only
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectAll()
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()

    pages = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:"+str(25833), layer.name(), "memory")

    fid = QgsField("fid", QVariant.Int, "int")
    attributes = [fid]
    pages.startEditing()
    pagesProvider = pages.dataProvider()
    pagesProvider.addAttributes(attributes)
    curs = 0
    numpages = geom.length()/(width)
    step = 1.0/numpages
    stepnudge = (1.0-overlap) * step
    print(3)
    pageFeatures = []
    r = 1
    while curs <= 1:
        startpoint =  geom.interpolate(curs*geom.length())
        endpoint = geom.interpolate((curs+step)*geom.length())
        ##### Null geometry cannot be converted to a point ######
        x_start = startpoint.asPoint().x()
        y_start = startpoint.asPoint().y()
        x_end = endpoint.asPoint().x()
        y_end = endpoint.asPoint().y()
        currline = QgsGeometry().fromWkt('LINESTRING({} {}, {} {})'.format(x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end))
        currpoly = QgsGeometry().fromWkt(
            'POLYGON((0 0, 0 {height},{width} {height}, {width} 0, 0 0))'.format(height=height, width=width))
        currpoly.translate(0,-height/2)
        azimuth = startpoint.asPoint().azimuth(endpoint.asPoint())

        currpoly.translate(x_start, y_start)
        currpoly.asPolygon()
        page = currpoly
        curs = curs + stepnudge
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setAttributes([r])
        feat.setGeometry(page)
        pageFeatures.append(feat)
        r = r + 1

    pagesProvider.addFeatures(pageFeatures)
    pages.commitChanges()

    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(pages, gridPath, "utf-8", pages.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
    layer_loaded = iface.addVectorLayer(gridPath, "Grid", "ogr")
```

And here comes the lazy answer for my problem after the problem was identified by ndawson (lazy answer kills the last polygon, there will be a better answer)

```
while curs <= 1:
    curs = curs + stepnudge
    if (curs+step) <=1:
        startpoint =  geom.interpolate(curs*geom.length())
        endpoint = geom.interpolate((curs+step)*geom.length())
        x_start = startpoint.asPoint().x()
        y_start = startpoint.asPoint().y()
        x_end = endpoint.asPoint().x()
        y_end = endpoint.asPoint().y()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x_start = startpoint.asPoint().x()` is triggering the null geometry warning, then it implies that `startPoint` is itself a null geometry. The only way this is possible is if `QgsGeometry.interpolate` returns a null geometry.

From the `interpolate` documentation:

"If the original geometry is a point type, a null geometry will be returned.... If the input is a NULL geometry, the output will also be a NULL geometry.". It also seems that calling interpolate with too large a distance for the geometry returns a null geometry.

So there's three options:

1. One (or more) of the input features has a null geometry
2. One (or more) of the input features has a point geometry
3. `(curs+step)` is > 1

The behavior of asPoint() did change in 3.4 -- previously if the geometry could not be converted to a point (e.g., it was null), then a point with coordinates 0,0 was returned instead. This silently lead to many errors or unexpected results, so the explicit exceptions are now thrown instead.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer! The winner is --> Number 3;-) I always check the changelog, but could not find what happened after 3.4.1. I postet the lazy answer for my problem below the question.

Comment: No problem -- it's good to see that the exception is working as intended here, and helping identify and flag tricky issues like this.