# Creating a tile layer for a polygon for use in QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, atlas

I want to create a series of plans at a set scale that covers a large area defined by a polygon.  The polygons are a buffer for a water network, so is very irregular with sections that are long and skinny.

Is there a way to create a set of rectangular tiles that covers the polygon, that I can then use the Atlas feature in QGIS 3,8. Ideally the rectangular tiles could be rotated to better accommodate the long skinny sections, but this is not critical.

A copy of the polygon I want to tile over is below.  There would be a large number of plans, as I want to generate the plans at say 1:20,000 scale to enable viewing of detail.  I would use the plans to print a number of plans with different themes, which I would periodically regenerate.
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem and het some inspiration from here:
[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173127/generating-equal-sized-polygons-along-line-with-pyqgis/173945](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173127/generating-equal-sized-polygons-along-line-with-pyqgis/173945)

Comment: You could make a `minimum oriented bounding box` for each feature, and split them manually. And/or try the solutions to this question about creating an oriented grid inside a polygon: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/258912/81764